# Linking a classic page to a fluid page in peoplesoft

Tags: oracle, peoplesoft

I have a problem with my classic page that is linked to my fluid page. When you click on the link, the classic page is
somewhat missarranged, though this is not the case with the page in the Application Designer. It was ok the previous 
days but became somewhat missarranged after some patching by oracle.

Any ideas what caused this and how to address this?

Really appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Are you running a multilanguage environment?

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your reply. No I am not running a multilanguage environment but this has already been addressed the recent patching. Thanks!